# Timely polling console app with time indicator that exits on ctrl+c

Tags: go, channel

I would like to pool for a token in on a timely base. The Token itself got also information about when it expires.
This should run forever until the user enters ctrl+c.

I tried the same with

```
span := timeLeft(*expDate)
timer := time.NewTimer(span).C
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5).C
```

which also does not work (the application hangs after count down). So I decided to try it with `<- time.After(...)`

This is my code that does not work. You will see the count down but it never breaks on expiration.

This is is a small extract with the polling logic for simplicity sake in a main.go:

```
func refreshToken() (time.Time, error) {
        //This should simulate a http request and returns the new target date for the next refresh
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        return time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second), nil
    }

func timeLeft(d time.Time) time.Duration {
    exactLeft := d.Sub(time.Now())
    floorSeconds := math.Floor(exactLeft.Seconds())
    return time.Duration(floorSeconds) * time.Second
}

func poller(expDate *time.Time) {
    exp := timeLeft(*expDate)

    done := make(chan bool)
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    for {
        select {

        // print time left on the screen
        case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
            go func() {
                fmt.Printf("\rNext Token refresh will be in: %v", timeLeft(*expDate))
            }()
        // mark as done when date is due
        case <-time.After(exp):
            fmt.Println("Refresh token now!")
            done <- true

        // exit app
        case <-c:
            os.Exit(0)
            break

        // exit function when done
        case <-done:
            break
        }

    }
}

func main() {

    var expiration time.Time
    expiration = time.Now().Add(10 * time.Second)
    // loop and refresh token as long as the app does not exit
    for {
        poller(&expiration)

        ex, err := refreshToken()
        expiration = ex
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("next round poller")
    }
}
```

I am also not sure if I need the done channel at all?
What is required to listen to two timers and call itself until someone hits ctrl+c?

Comment: I'd say that your program hangs as the `done` channel is unbuffered - that means that your program will hang when you try to write into it as there is nothing reading from it.

Comment: isn't that the 3rd case?

Comment: You mean fourth (`case <-done: break`). Program never reaches to it as it will hang on the line `done <- true` - becaure channel is unbuffered it can't be written to unless there is reader ready. And there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. While @ain was right wit the buffered done channel, it is not really required in the code now. It worked without it.

The trick did have the `timer`outside of the for loop and the `ticker` within it. Reason is the `time.After`is a `func`that return a new channel on every iteration. This seams perfectly fine for the ticker, but not for the `timer`.
With the following changes it worked =) ...

```
   func poller(expDate *time.Time) {
        exp := timeLeft(*expDate)
        timer := time.After(exp)

        fmt.Printf("Next Token refresh will be in: %v\n", exp)

        c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
        for {
            select {

            // print time left on the screen
            case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
                go func() {
                    fmt.Printf("\r     ")
                    fmt.Printf("\r%v", timeLeft(*expDate))
                }()
            // mark as done when date is due
            case <-timer:
                fmt.Println("Refresh token now!")
                return

            // exit app
            case <-c:
                os.Exit(0)
                break

            }
        }
    }
```